# VBA executes a .bat but overwrites a cd in the .bat

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file, vbscript, excel-2010

Heyho, I ran into a strange problem.

I execute a line like this in my VBA:

```
Shell "path_to_my_bat\batname.bat"
```

The content of the bat is very simple as well:

```
cd c:\some_path\
copy *csv newfiles.txt
```

What it does is simply take all csvs in the directory and merges them into one .txt that I use further down the line in the macro.

The problem is, since I have played around with some vbs scripts it seems I have changed something about how the shell command works.

The "cd" command seems to be skipped, or overwritten by something, the actual second part of the bat is executed in the directory my Workbook is placed in.
Luckily I had a .csv lying there or else I would not have noticed...

The bat on itself works fine if I don't run it from VBA.

The vbs script I played with looks like this (it should open a file and execute a macro in there) :

I think I overwrote some kind of default setting that I should not have tinkered with...
Apart from that I have done nothing I'm aware of to alter something. The macro was working fine this morning, but now because of the bat error it is useless.

```
' Create a WshShell to get the current directory
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' Create an Excel instance
Dim myExcelWorker
Set myExcelWorker = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 

' Disable Excel UI elements
myExcelWorker.DisplayAlerts = False
myExcelWorker.AskToUpdateLinks = False
myExcelWorker.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False
myExcelWorker.FeatureInstall = msoFeatureInstallNone

' Tell Excel what the current working directory is 
' (otherwise it can't find the files)
Dim strSaveDefaultPath
Dim strPath
strSaveDefaultPath = myExcelWorker.DefaultFilePath
strPath = WshShell.CurrentDirectory
myExcelWorker.DefaultFilePath = strPath

' Open the Workbook specified on the command-line 
Dim oWorkBook
Dim strWorkerWB
strWorkerWB = strPath & "\YourWorkbook.xls"

Set oWorkBook = myExcelWorker.Workbooks.Open(strWorkerWB)

' Build the macro name with the full path to the workbook
Dim strMacroName
strMacroName = "'" & strPath & "\YourWorkbook" & 
    "!Sheet1.YourMacro"
on error resume next 
   ' Run the calculation macro
   myExcelWorker.Run strMacroName
   if err.number <> 0 Then
      ' Error occurred - just close it down.
   End If
   err.clear
on error goto 0 

oWorkBook.Save 

myExcelWorker.DefaultFilePath = strSaveDefaultPath

' Clean up and shut down
Set oWorkBook = Nothing

' Don’t Quit() Excel if there are other Excel instances 
' running, Quit() will 
shut those down also
if myExcelWorker.Workbooks.Count = 0 Then
   myExcelWorker.Quit
End If

Set myExcelWorker = Nothing
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

If it helps, I'm running Windows 8.1 64 bit with Excel 2010 64bit
Got full admin acces etc.

Comment: Are you running from a different drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your current directory is on the D: drive, then `cd c:\some_path\` will set the directory for C:, but your current drive will remain somewhere on D:. You need to tell cmd.exe to actually change which drive you are working in.

Simply change your command to

```
cd /d c:\some_path\
```

or

```
pushd c:\some_path\
```

Comment: yep that solves the problem. Thanks!
My question now is: Why did it work in the first place. The bat and the xlsm were always in different directories on different hard drives.
But yeah, I guess Problem is solved :)